# Get url/file path from existing NSInputStream

Tags: ios

Is there any way to get the URL / file path from an existing `NSInputStream`?

It seems like a silly question, but I'm using a 3rd party framework (parse) that provides me with an `NSInputStream` and I need to actually find out the location of the underlying file.

Comment: Looking at the NSInputStream and NSStream class reference, I can't see anything related to the location of the underlying file.

Comment: Neither could I. I was hoping it might be possible through `valueForKey` or something.

Comment: As we can create a NSInputStream instance with `+ (id)inputStreamWithData:(NSData *)data`, so maybe you shouldn't suppose it is backed with a file or url.

Comment: I know that in this case it will almost certainly not be backed with `NSData`. The API is exposed to enable you to incrementally process large files, that you wouldn't want to load into memory as `NSData`.

Comment: Actually I didn't find any interface about that either. Why not create a file and fill it with the NSInputStream.

Comment: I'm receiving the `NSInputStream` from a call to a Parse object (I have no control over it). I've figured out how to solve my problem now though. Thanks for your help folks!